# Пирамида из чисел на С++. От 1 до 9. Вот сам код

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    if (1 <= N && N <= 9)
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
                cout << j;
                if (j != i)
                    cout << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    else {
        cout << "N is wrong: " << N;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Работает правильно но после окончание цикла, например я выводил 3 результат:

```
1
1_2
1_2_3
______
```

конце есть еще пустая строка. Вопрос такой как убрать эту пустую строку. Буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да нет там никакой пустой строки... Курсор переходит на новую строку. Перенаправьте вывод в файл и убедитесь, что никаких пустых строк нет.

Comment: В hex-viewer'е для ввода 1 - `0000000000: 31 0D 0A`. Вот тут - https://ideone.com/qu3eQb - добавил после вашего вывода еще одну строку, чтоб было видно, что никакой пустой строки нет. Может, от вас требуют, чтобы последняя строка была не законченной?... Без символа перехода на новую строку (последнего `endl`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, от вас хотят странного (и, с моей точки зрения, глупого).

Попробуйте удовлетворить их требования так - вместо

```
cout << endl;
```

напишите

```
if (i < N) cout << endl;
```

Но это бред...

Comment: Да ты прав это полный бред

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь